# JetPack Compose - using State Hoisting

Tags: android, kotlin, state, android-jetpack-compose

Starting to Learn JetPack Compose. I'm struggling now with State hosting. I have this simple example to press a Button to show in a Text component the content of an array. I'm able to make it work if the variable is inside my @Composable. When applying State Hoisting (taking the variable for my composable) I'm finding some issues.

This is the code that is working fine

```
 var listadoNumeros = listOf<Int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
 NextValue(listadoNumeros)

 @Composable
    fun NextValue(listado: List<Int>) {
        var position by rememberSaveable {mutableStateOf (0)}
    
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround
            ){
            Text(text = "Value in Array ${listado[position]}")
            Button(onClick = { position += 1 }) {
                Text(text = "Next")
            }}}
```

This is the code that is not working correctly

```
    var listadoNumeros = listOf<Int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    var n by rememberSaveable {mutableStateOf (0)}
    NextValue(position = n,listadoNumeros)

@Composable
fun NextValue(position:Int,listado: List<Int>) {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround

    ) {
        Text(text = "Value in Array ${listado[position]}")
        Button(onClick = { position += 1 }) {
            Text(text = "Next")
        }}}
```

Error message, as you can expect, is "**position** can't be reassigned". I see why, but don't know how to fix it. I read about onValueChanged in TextField, etc, but don't know if it's applicable here.

Answer (score 4):

`position += 1` is equivalent to `position = position + 1`. In Kotlin, function arguments are `val` and cannot be reassigned within the scope of the function. That is why the compiler will complain and prevent you from doing that.

What you want to do is to add an extra event callback within the function and perform this addition at the function call site.

```
@Composable
fun NextValue(position: Int, listado: List<Int>, onPositionChange: (Int) -> Unit) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround

    ) {
        Text(text = "Value in Array ${listado[position]}")
        Button(onClick = { onPositionChange(position + 1) }) {
            Text(text = "Next")
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the above composable as

```
val listadoNumeros = listOf<Int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
var n by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
NextValue(position = n, listadoNumeros, onPositionChange = { newPosition -> n = newPosition})
```

Whenever the user clicks on the button, an event is sent back up to the caller and the caller decides what to do with the updated information. In this case, recreate the composable with an updated value.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rafsanjani!. Appreciated your quick reply. It´s seems so easy when you explain it in this way.  Merry Christmas!